# how to merge several audio files(they are different format) to by using ffmpeg command?

Tags: audio, merge, ffmpeg

I want to merge several audio files(they are different format eg. mp3 , m4a , wav)  to by using ffmpeg command and  output the result to highest quality audio format.

Comment: One after each other, or all at same time?

Comment: You didn't provide much info. For example, what output format(s) do you want?

Answer (score 0):

Convert them all to a common format, let's say AAC, and then [concatenate the results](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Concatenate).

You can use a shell script or any other form of script to do it.